# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I'm working on a windows form project and it creates a PDF file. I want to save file where user want it to. I use a SaveFileDialog for this. When I click "Save as a PDF" button on my form I get this error code.

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

If I don't use the SaveFileDialog (If I give a static name for the file), don't get the error.

Here is button click code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();


        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDosya = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 10, 10);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDosya, new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create));//TODO dosya ismi
            pdfDosya.Open();
        }
     }
```

How can I solve the problem.

Comment: Just a side note (not the answer to your question). Use `if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` instead of `if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")`.

Comment: Also, `Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) == "MyDocuments"`, doesn't yield a path.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: In which line you getting the error?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added try catch for saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() line. I get this error now. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: @PraveenVR "saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();" this line.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the properties of the save file dialog object to see if any of them are causing problems? Start with commenting away all of them. Does that work? Then reintroduce one by one.

Comment: tried all the combinations but still having the same problem.

Comment: You need to isolate this - make the smallest example possible - which does nothing else (prior to calling the Save dialog) but this. See if it happens still. If it doesn't it means something's done before that's the issue. If it repeats then you have a clear small example you can post or test further

Comment: What is `PdfWriter`? Is it 3rd party component? Is it .NET library?

Comment: @NSGaga should I include the ITextSharp in this project or not?

Comment: @Maciej it's an ITextSharp library type.

Comment: try both ways - but unless you have something else dealing with unmanaged code then you'll probably need it. Try it and see - cut just  to that section that loads and saves the file. If still problems, then try w/o ITextSharp. That's the best (not gonna say the 'only') way to deal w/ these problems.

Comment: @NSGaga I tried the both ways. I created a new project. Added only a button into it. I added the codes I writed below. And it works fine. The problem is in my real project. But I don't what I must do to solve it? It gives me a headache!

Comment: :) welcome to coding - you keep 'adding' until you see what's the 'point of bother' - start from that 'working minimal' and add things that your 'real project' has - but one by one - until it doesn't work again. There're tools to help but I don't know from memory, it was a long time.

Comment: @NSGaga thanks for your help. I'll try them to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the problem:

You can't use `Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to get the folder path as a string, it's only a enum. You need to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to get the path as a string for the enum value.

Comment: This can get you the wrong folder but not "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory =   Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

   if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
   {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F,100.0F,0.0F);
        document.AddTitle("FileName.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        document.Open();
    }
```

Comment: but I get the error before the if block. because of this code cannot go into if block.

Comment: make if statement as if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) and try again

Comment: "if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)" this line.

Comment: I have edited the whole answer.Copy the entire code and try again. Let me know the line getting the error

Comment: Are you sure the line  if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) is the exception statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot  
Please see the link to view the details of error you getting.