# HRESULT: 0x80270254 in Windows Phone Programming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am having trouble win visual studio 2013. Whenever I create new project for windows phone 8.1 application, the MainPage.xaml works fine until I restart or shutdown my laptop . But when I turn on my laptop and try to open that existing project the MainPage.xaml does not load. It says

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80270254)
```

Here is the full error details.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80270254)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.AppPackage.WrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: That's weird and wrong and probably means you need to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio. Something got messed up. If you want to try and figure it out without reinstalling, then you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Is there any official Microsoft response to this problem? I'm having it with Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013. Restarting visual studio didn't work. I'm testing repairing it

Comment: You can repair and install latest update (update 4 http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-update4-rtm-vs). I couldn't find any official response to this problem @CamiloMartinez

Comment: Actually, I just needed to repair it @TusharTushKhush. I haven't installed the update 4 but it is working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated my vs with update 4 and the problem gone.

Comment: I have Update 4 and the problem exists.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev which OS are you using?

Comment: I had the same problem, installing Update 4 didnt work for me either. I went to the installed programs list and started a repair installation of VS. It works again yay :)

Comment: First I had windows 10 technical preview. I installed the vs 2013 with update 2. I got the problem. I thought problem lies with OS. Then installed 8.1 and got the same problem again. And finally update 4 helped me get rid of it. That makes me think that update 4 is the solution.

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1. I restarted the Studio and it started to work. Very strange issue.

Comment: @TusharTushKhush I didn't have the issue _until_ installing Update 4.  Trying a repair now...

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case helped re-install Visual Studio.
It takes a long time, especially "Configuring your system, this may take a while" part, but the problem's solved.
My environment: Windows 8.1 Pro x64 + Visual Studio 2013 Community

Comment: It actually takes quite a while but repairing worked also in my case.

Answer (score 0):

read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24772492/416210, it's just an attempt but it solved the issue for me with just a reboot.