# Failure Could not find file ...App.g.i.cs

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to stop this error appearing in the Intellisense section in the Output window in Visual Studio: 
**[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\code\CatApp\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.i.cs'.**

I've cleared obj and bin folders, upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017,cleared all nuget packages and checked my project out from SVN again.

I get the same problem if I create a new UWP project. (Every time I create a new UWP project, I have to get the Nuget package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform separately. I'm wondering if the two problems could be related.)

My target and min version are 16299.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259603/g-i-cs-files-missing-classes-no-longer-contain-a-definition-for-initializecompo ?

Comment: Well, related, when Nuget can't retrieve the package by itself then IntelliSense is doomed as well.  You'll need to dig up a diagnostic to get ahead, look in the Output window and switch "Show output from" to Package Manager to get the Nuget download trace.

Comment: Could you please add the version of visual studio you are using as well as the version of UniversalWindowsPlatform I ran into a problem similar to this if my univsersal windows platform was not set to 5.2 and using Visual Studio 2015 Service pack 3.

Comment: I would suggest trying to repair whole Visual Studio. It is very unusual for this to happen with blank app.

Comment: I'm running 15.5.7+27130.2036

Comment: UniversalWindowsPlatform is now being automatically added to new projects. I repaired VS, decided on Windows Version 14393 and UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.0.8 that I'll stick to, then cleared all Nuget caches. The output window is still complaining about missing *.g.i.cs files though :(

Comment: I cleared ShadowCache in %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_9dbf4983\Designer. I thought this had fixed it, but it hasn't.

Comment: This is still a problem for me on `VisualStudio.16.Preview/16.4.0-pre.1.0+29319.158`.