# App crashes with Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, exception, memory, protected, unhandled

Please someone can tell me about what could possibly be causing this error below :

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>          at System.String.wcslen(Char* ptr)
>          at System.String.CtorCharPtr(Char* ptr)
>          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr ptr)
>          at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.GetUserPreferenceCategory(Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanging(Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at My.Program.Main(String[] args)

Application: My.exe (C#)
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Installed .Net Framework : 4.5.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot)

Comment: Try running the application as Administrator. If you are debugging via VS, then run VS as Administrator.

Comment: What in your code is making the crash?

Comment: It could be that you are passing a string literal (`"Some Text"`) to a function that is expecting a string it can modify.  But without your code that's just a shot in the dark, which is coincidentally what .... :)