# FatalExecutionEngineError on async method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, c#-8.0

Alright. So I've went ahead and rewrote most of the code, according to the articles I was pointed to.

It looks like this:

```
Progress<string, string> progressIndicator;
public void ShowTEF()
{
            progressIndicator = new Progress<(string body, string title)>(AtualizaUI);
            ComunicaComTEF(progressIndicator);
}

private async Task<int> ComunicaComTEF(IProgress<(string body, string title)> progress)
        {
            int retorno = 10000;
            return await Task.Run<int>(() =>
            {
                while (retorno == 10000)
                {
                    if (estadoTEF != StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao && estadoTEF != StateTEF.RetornaMenuAnterior)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("estadoTEF != OperacaoPadrao. Awaiting response");
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("estadoTEF == OperacaoPadrao");
                        retorno = ContinuaVendaTEF();
                    }
                    if (progress != null)
                        progress.Report((mensagemJanela, tituloJanela));
                }
                if (retorno < 0) this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DialogBox.Show("ERRO DE TEF", DialogBox.DialogBoxButtons.No, DialogBox.DialogBoxIcons.Error, true, "Erro!"));
                if (statusAtual != StatusTEF.Confirmado) statusAtual = StatusTEF.Erro;
                Debug.WriteLine("Closing window due to loop ending");
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
                StatusChanged?.Invoke(this, new TEFEventArgs() { TipoDoTEF = _tipoTEF, Valor = valor, idMetodo = _idMetodo, status = statusAtual });
                return 0;
            });
        }

        private int ContinuaVendaTEF()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferTEF).Split('\0')[0], 0);
            var retorno = ContinuaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(ref Comando, ref TipoCampo, ref TamMinimo, ref TamMaximo, bufferTEF, bufferTEF.Length, 0);
            ProcessaComando(Comando, bufferTEF);
            LimpaBuffer();
            return retorno;
        }
```

`ProcessaComando` is a switch that, depending on `comando` does something, like showing a message

```
private void ExibeMensagemOperador(byte[] buffer)
{
    tituloJanela = "OPERAÇÃO NO TEF";
    mensagemJanela = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Split('\0')[0];
}
```

Or asking the user to press any key

```
public void PerguntaSimOuNao(byte[] pergunta)
{
    estadoTEF = StateTEF.AguardaSimNao;
    mensagemJanela = "(S)im / (N)ão";
    tituloJanela = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pergunta).Split('\0')[0];
}
```

Which is then captured by a `PreviewTextInput`

```
private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        if (estadoTEF == StateTEF.AguardaSimNao && (e.Text.ToUpper() == "S" || e.Text.ToUpper() == "N"))
        {
            LimpaBuffer();
            if (e.Text.ToUpper() == "S")
            {
                bufferTEF = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0");
                estadoTEF = StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao;
                ComunicaComTEF(progressIndicator);
            }
            else if (e.Text.ToUpper() == "N")
            {
                bufferTEF = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1");
                estadoTEF = StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao;
                ComunicaComTEF(progressIndicator);
            }
        }
```

Now, for the new information. When I run it using Task, with NO async/await, just returning a Task and its result synchronously triggers the FatalExecutionError. If `ComunicaComTef` to int, and remove the `Task.Run` (just running the code synchronously), the error is not triggered, and the loop runs flawlessly.

---

Previous version of the question, if needed:

> I've been learning async programming for the last few months, and I've
>   found an error I don't know how to debug/handle:
>
> Here's the setup. I have a window `ShowTEF`, which calls two methods,
>   `IniciaFuncaoSitef` and `async ComunicaComTEF`. Both of them call
>   external dll methods, which return integer values and a byte[] by ref.
>
> `IniciaFuncaoSitef` simply starts an operation, by providing some
>   parameters to the external dll. `ComunicaComTEF` has a `while` loop,
>   that, for each sync call for the external method calls a
>   `this.Dispatcher.Invoke()` to refresh the UI. Here's the simplified
>   code:
>
> ````
>         public void ShowTEF(TipoTEF tipoTEF, decimal vlrTEF)
>         {
>             Topmost = true;
>             InitializeComponent();
>             Show();
>             IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo((int)tipoTEF, (vlrTEF*100).ToString("0.00")); //Starts a new interation with the
> external DLL.
>             stateTEF=StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao; //Allows the while loop on ComunicaComTEF to run
>             statusTEF = StatusTEF.EmAndamento; //This will be used by ShowTEF's caller to know what was the outcome of the operation.
>             ComunicaComTEF();
>         }
>
>         private async void ComunicaComTEF()
>         {
>             int retorno = 10000;
>             await Task.Run(() =>
>             {
>                 while (retorno == 10000) //The external DLL returns 10000 as long as it needs my software to keep communicating with it.
>                 {
>                     if (stateTEF != StateTEF.CancelamentoRequisitado) //If there still stuff to do, and the user hasn't cancelled, the loop
> falls here.
>                     {
>                         if (stateTEF != StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao) //If the DLL asked some user interaction, the loop falls here.
>                         {
>                             this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => AtualizaUI());
>                             return;
>                         }
>                         else //If the DLL is still "chatting" with my software, the loop goes on.
>                         {
>                             retorno = ContinuaVendaTEF().intRetorno;
>                             this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => AtualizaUI());
>                         }
>                     }
>                     else //If the user presses Escape at any time, it will fall here at the next loop.
>                     {
>                         statusTEF = StatusTEF.Cancelado;
>                         retorno = CancelaOperacaoAtual();
>                         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
>                         return;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 string msgErro = retorno switch //These are actual error messages I've shortened here to save space
>                 {
>                     -1 => "ERRMESS1",
>                     -3 => "ERRMESS3",
>                     -4 => "ERRMESS4",
>                     -5 => "ERRMESS5",
>                     -8 => "ERRMESS8",
>                     -9 => "ERRMESS9",
>                     -10 => "ERRMESS10",
>                     -12 => "ERRMESS12",
>                     -20 => "ERRMESS20",
>                     -40 => "ERRMESS40",
>                     _ => "NAE" //Not an Error
>                 };
>                 if (msgErro != "NAE") this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DialogBox.Show((msgErro)); //DialogBox inherits Window but has some
> custom parameters, like custom icons and custom buttons.
>                 if (statusTEF != StatusTEF.Confirmado) statusTEF = StatusTEF.Erro; //If, when the loop ends when return != 10000, the
> status is not confirmed, it understands there has been an error.
>                 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close()); //Closes the current window.
>                 StatusChanged?.Invoke(this, new TEFEventArgs() { TipoDoTEF = _tipoTEF, Valor = valor, idMetodo = _idMetodo, status =
> statusTEF }); //Alerts whoever called ShowTEF about the new status.
>                 return;
>             });
>         }
>
>         private (int intRetorno, string msgRetorno) ContinuaVendaTEF()
>         {
>             int retorno = ContinuaFuncaoSiTefInterativo(ref Comando, ref TipoCampo, bufferTEF, bufferTEF.Length);
>             ProcessaComando(bufferTEF, bufferTEF.Length);
>             ClearBuffer();
>             return (retorno, "NORETURN");
>         }
>               private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
>         {
>             if (stateTEF == StateTEF.AguardaMenu && e.Text.IsNumbersOnly())
>             {
>                     int opcaoEscolhida = int.Parse(e.Text);
>                     ClearBuffer();
>                     bufferTEF = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(opcaoEscolhida.ToString());
>                     stateTEF = StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao;
>                     ComunicaComTEF();
>             }
>             else if (stateTEF == StateTEF.AguardaSimNao && (e.Text.ToUpper() == "S" || e.Text.ToUpper() == "N"))
>             {
>                 ClearBuffer();
>                 if (e.Text.ToUpper() == "S")
>                 {
>                     bufferTEF = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0");
>                 }
>                 else if (e.Text.ToUpper() == "N")
>                 {
>                     bufferTEF = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1");
>                 }
>               stateTEF = StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao;
>               ComunicaComTEF();
>             } ```
>
> `IniciaFuncaoSiTefInterativo` and `ContinuaFuncaoSiTefInterativo` are
> the external methods imported using a DllImport with StdCall
> convention. `ProcessaComando` reads `Comando`, `TipoCampo` and
> `bufferTEF` and changes `stateTEF` to a different state from
> `OperacaoPadrao` so that the loop is broken and the user has to
> interact with the software. There is a `Window_KeyDown` and
> `Window_PreviewTextInput` that captures keystrokes as long as stateTEF
> is not OperacaoPadrao, processes it (storing the appropriate result in
> bufferTEF) and calls `ComunicaComTEF` back again.
>
> ----------
>
> So that's it for the code. Now the issue. Sometimes the process runs
> flawlessly, but sometimes I get the following error:
>
> > Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in
> 'M:\TrilhaWorkSpace\AmbiPDV-NFVenda\PDV_PRINCIPAL\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\AmbiPDV.exe'.
> Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The
> address of the error was at 0xf5b029e1, on thread 0x72bc. The error
> code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the
> unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this
> bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which
> may corrupt the stack.
>
> I've tried enabling Managed Compatibility Mode
> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56846918/keyvaultclient-throws-fatalexecutionengineerror-on-debug-randomly),
> but I still get the same error. I've also tried disabling Diagnostics
> Tools when debugging. 
>
> Any hints on how should I tackle this issue? I can provide any further
> info required, of course.
>
>
> ----------
>
> EDIT.: Here's the Call Stack
>
> >     [Managed to Native Transition]      WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) + 0xbb bytes   
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> frame) + 0x4d bytes    
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
> ignore) + 0x60 bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
> window) + 0x7a bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window
> window) + 0x2e bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1e
> bytes     AmbiPDV.exe!PDV_WPF.App.Main() + 0x5a bytes 
>
>
> ----------
>
> EDIT 04/02/2020
>
> As per @PanagiotisKanavos, I've adopted IProgress to better update my
> interface to show information (and request it) from the user. 
>
> ``` public async Task ShowTEF(TipoTEF tipoTEF, decimal vlrTEF) { ...
> //ComunicaComTEF(); var progressIndicator = new Progress<(string,
> string)>(AtualizaUI); await ComunicaComTEF(progressIndicator); }
>
> private async Task ComunicaComTEF(IProgress<(string, string)>
> progress) { await Task.Run(() =>
>     {
>         while (retorno == 10000)
>         {
>             progress.Report((message, title));
>             if (estadoTEF != StateTEF.CancelamentoRequisitado)
>             {
>                 if (estadoTEF != StateTEF.OperacaoPadrao)
>                 {
>                     return;//Not sure if this should be return or break...
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     retorno = ContinuaVendaTEFAsync().Result;
>                 }
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 statusAtual = StatusTEF.Cancelado;
>                 retorno = CancelaOperacaoAtual().Result;
>                 this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Close());
>                 return;
>             }
>         } ... } private void AtualizaUI((string body, string titulo) item) {
>     tbl_Body.Text = item.body.TrimEnd('\0'); //<------ Error thrown here------
>     lbl_Title.Text = item.titulo.TrimEnd('\0'); } ```
>
> Now I'm getting a different error. Right at the "tbl_Body.Text" line,
> I got a `System.AccessViolationException` error. Here's the stack
> trace:
>
> > AmbiPDV.exe!PDV_WPF.Telas.SiTEFBox.AtualizaUI(System.ValueTuple<string,string>
> item = {System.ValueTuple<string,string>}) Line 533 + 0x3 bytes   C# 
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Progress<System.ValueTuple<string,string>>.InvokeHandlers(object
> state) + 0x5e bytes    
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
> callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0xae bytes   
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
> source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate
> callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler =
> null) + 0x35 bytes     
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
> + 0xdd bytes      WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object
> state) + 0x3f bytes    
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object
> obj) + 0x42 bytes  
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xc4 bytes  
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x17 bytes  
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) + 0x44 bytes    
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext
> executionContext = {MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext},
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9a bytes 
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
> + 0x50 bytes      WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() +
> 0x176 bytes    
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr
> hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool
> handled) + 0x5c bytes  
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd =
> 5967824, int msg = 49656, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr
> lParam = 0, ref bool handled = false) + 0xa1 bytes     
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object
> o) + 0x6c bytes    
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
> callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x52 bytes   
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
> source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate
> callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler =
> null) + 0x35 bytes     
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
> priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object
> args, int numArgs) + 0x142 bytes   
>   WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr
> hwnd = 5967824, int msg = 49656, System.IntPtr wParam = 0,
> System.IntPtr lParam = 0) + 0xf4 bytes        [Native to Managed
> Transition]       [Managed to Native Transition]   
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) + 0xbb bytes   
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> frame) + 0x4d bytes    
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
> ignore) + 0x60 bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
> window) + 0x7a bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window
> window) + 0x2e bytes   
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1e
> bytes     AmbiPDV.exe!PDV_WPF.App.Main() + 0x5a bytes 
>
> I read @
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417900/app-crashes-with-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory
> that this could be caused by passing string literals to functions that
> expected them to be mutable. However, I believe this is not the case,
> as I rewrote `AtualizaUI()` as follows:
> ````
>
> ````
>     private void AtualizaUI((string body, string titulo) item)
>     {
>         string a = item.body.TrimEnd('\0');
>         string b = item.titulo.TrimEnd('\0');
>         tbl_Body.Text = a;
>         lbl_Title.Text = b;
>     } ```
> ````
>
> And once again, I triggered the previous `FatalExecutionError`. Here's
>   the stack strace:
>
> > AmbiPDV.exe!PDV_WPF.Telas.SiTEFBox.AtualizaUI(System.ValueTuple
> >     item = {System.ValueTuple}) Line 536 + 0xc bytes   C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Progress>.InvokeHandlers(object
> >     state) + 0x5e bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
> >     callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0xae bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
> >     source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate
> >     callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler =
> >     null) + 0x35 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
> >     + 0xdd bytes      WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object
> >     state) + 0x3f bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object
> >     obj) + 0x42 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xc4 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x17 bytes
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> >     executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> >     state) + 0x44 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext
> >     executionContext = {MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext},
> >     System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9a bytes 
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
> >     + 0x50 bytes      WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() +
> >     0x176 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr
> >     hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool
> >     handled) + 0x5c bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd =
> >     4458568, int msg = 49656, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr
> >     lParam = 0, ref bool handled = false) + 0xa1 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object
> >     o) + 0x6c bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate
> >     callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x52 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object
> >     source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate
> >     callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler =
> >     null) + 0x35 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority
> >     priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object
> >     args, int numArgs) + 0x142 bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr
> >     hwnd = 4458568, int msg = 49656, System.IntPtr wParam = 0,
> >     System.IntPtr lParam = 0) + 0xf4 bytes        [Native to Managed
> >     Transition]       [Managed to Native Transition]
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> >     frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) + 0xbb bytes
> >       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame
> >     frame) + 0x4d bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object
> >     ignore) + 0x60 bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window
> >     window) + 0x7a bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window
> >     window) + 0x2e bytes
> >       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1e
> >     bytes     AmbiPDV.exe!PDV_WPF.App.Main() + 0x5a bytes
>
> On a side note, I'd like to thank you for pointing me to that article
>   about IProgress. It makes much more sense than lots of await and async
>   voids!

Comment: Please, share the call stack

Comment: Added the call stack

Comment: `async void` is *only* meant for event handlers. Change your method syntax to `async Task` at least. Another problem is the attempt to modify the UI from inside a Task. That's what `await` is for - return execution to the UI context so you *don't* need to use `Invoke`

Comment: This means that `ShowEF` should be `async Task` itself, so it can use `await ComunicaComTEF()`. That method should be `async Task ComunicaComTEF()`. Instead of wrapping mainly UI code in `Task.Run`, *only* the parts that really need to run in the background should be run this way. This code doesn't seem to contain anything that needs `Task.Run` though, it's mainly UI updates

Comment: Is `ContinuaVendaTEF()` the method that's blocking? That's the method that should be called inside `Task.Run` then. If you want to make polling calls in a tight loop, perhaps a better choice would be to use `IProgress<T>` as shown in [Enabling progress and cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) and decouple the UI updates from the polling loop

Comment: I would maybe take out the async calls and invest the design into just to run the tasks in background workers (threads) and then *only* invoking back to any VM/controls when necessary. Async is nice, but its not a full replacement for running items in background wokrers. With that said, divide an conquer the code by  putting each running operation into its own unit. Once you feel that unit works, move to the next, til the problem reappears or you gain insight into the failure.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've read the article you suggested, and I implemented IProgress, so ComunicaComTEF now expects a IProgress<(string, string)> parameter, while, for each loop progress.Report(message, title) is called with the current information to be shown to the user. I still get a different error, right when I call tbl_Body.Text = item.body.TrimEnd('\0') to set the new title on the window. I updating the question to reflect the changes done so far, as well as add the UI update method.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that this error only triggers on a very specific order of methods called, but either way of calling ShowTEF is similar, so I'm not sure that could affect it.

Comment: I've found some more symptoms: The error is thrown exactly when AtualizaUI tries to set tbl_Body.Text. I either get `FatalExecutionError` or `AccessViolationException`. Oh, and also, it looks like devenv.exe keeps the lock on the exe file after each debugging session, requiring me to restart VS every time.

Comment: I think the error has nothing to do with async/await. I've rewritten the code to conform with the correct utilization of async/await, and I still get the same error. I will shift my investigation to the external dll methods called. Even if I don't use async methods (forfeiting the interface update), I still get the same error... Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: ExecutionError means often unmanaged memory corruption.This is often caused by wrong PInvoke signatures. Try to enable MDA in VS to catch common errors there. Another source are your buffers. You have them in managed code passed by reference which can be GCed, moved while you call them. That can lead to funny race condidions where the GC thinks no one is using that array and moves the data around. That can lead to managed heap corruptions where you write to arbitrary locations in managed memory. Are you properly pinning your data?

Comment: Man, that was it! It is also my first time using unmanaged code. You were right, but not because it was not being pinned. Whenever I cleared my buffer, rather than fill it with \0, I instantiated a new one, hence, changing the address the external library would be looking at. Also, whenever I sent information via the buffer, rather than filling the same buffer with my info and padding with \0, I replaced the buffer with a new array with the same length my information was. Thanks for the insight, @AloisKraus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't actually related to asynch programming, initially, but because of unmanaged code and memory handling. Thanks to Alois, who pointed me in the right direction, I managed to find what was wrong.

The external library requires a fixed size byte array (22000 bytes, to be precise), and it must sit at the same address while the library and my software interact. Two big mistakes were made. First, every time I needed to clear the buffer so I could send information to the external library, I was using `bufferTEF = new buffer[22000]`. So, rather than clearing it, I was instancing a new one, hence changing its address, so the external library had issues finding it again. Second, whenever I sent data to the external library, I used `bufferTEF = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("information"))`, which, means I sent back an array with the same length as the information I sent. Since the external library expected a minimum of 20000 bytes, it exploded and didn't know what to do.