# Adding a panel in UserControl gives Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I am getting this nasty error every time I try to add a panel to any UserControl in the "Design" view.
Here is the Stack Trace:

```
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawRectangleI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen pen, Rectangle rect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.PanelDesigner.DrawBorder(Graphics graphics)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.PanelDesigner.OnPaintAdornments(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ScrollableControlDesigner.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I have checked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot) with the same exception but none of the answers fix my problem.

Also, I've tried to unchecked "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" and had no success.

Please, any advice?

Comment: Any code to show?  Anything in a paint event?

Comment: No, I created a new UserControl, and tried to add a panel (it happens to any container I try to add) and the Visual Studio crashes with this error

Comment: So this happens if you create a new project?

Comment: Just tried, and yes, it happens on a new project as well :( Visual Studio restarts

Comment: Do you have any add-ins?  Try rebooting machine.  Repair / Reinstall Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: Try `devenv /SafeMode`  and also `/ResetSkipPkgs` to open Visual Studio using `Run` window and create a new project and see if the problem still is there.

Comment: So, I reinstalled my Visual Studio, rebooted the machine and everything is working fine now, thanks so much guys!