# AutoComplete textBox from a certain position of each line of a .txt file

Tags: c#

I have a textBox named "textBoxCliente" and I want it to appear suggestions when I writte in there from the .txt file.
The suggestions that I want to appear from the .txt file are in the position 1 "parts[1]", each position are separated with the caracter "|".

My .txt file is this:

- 1|Rui|Lisboa|rui@hotmail.com|912345324|14/01/2000|89564352|Empresa
- 2|Henrique|Evora|henrique@hotmail.com|914445324|17/05/2001|55464352|Particular
- 3|Andre|Agueda|andre@hotmail.com|932415374|12/11/1996|23456743|Particular
- 4|Pedro|Aveiro|pedro@hotmail.com|965342163|30/03/2002|98645372|Empresa

My code is:

```
public partial class Vender : UserControl
{
    public Vender()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string dir = (Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Bd/clientes.txt");
    string[] sug = new string[File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + 
        "/Bd/clientes.txt").Count()];

    private void textBoxCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carrSug();

        for (int i = 0; i < sug.Length; i++)
        {
            textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(sug[i]);
        }

        textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    }

    private void carrSug()
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadLines(dir).ToArray();
        int nLine = File.ReadAllLines(dir).Count();

        for (int j = 0; j <= nLine - 1; j++)
        {
            string[] parts = lines[j].Split(new char[] { '|' });
            sug[j] = parts[1];
        }
    }
}
```

What I did was using the "string[] sug" to save the values of the position 1 of each line and then use it to show the suggestions.

Comment: Look at your code, please; especially the first few code lines of your _carrSug_ method... (more specifically, that 3rd code line there saying `sug = null;`)

Comment: I tried to removed it but it doens´t work aswell...

Comment: Get yourself some time and read some tutorials which teach how to create and work with arrays. It will be time well spent. :-)

Comment: I fixed the problem with the array. But I don´t get the autocomplete in the textBox. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a programmer, get better at *reading carefully*. Here is the documentation for `AutoCompleteCustomSource`:

> Gets or sets a custom System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection to use **when the System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.AutoCompleteSource property is set to CustomSource**.

<sub>Emphasis Mine</sub>

See the bolded part in the above, make sure you do that:

```
textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Also, you do not need to do that every time the user types. The event handler `textBoxCliente_TextChanged` will be called every time the text changes. Instead, put the code in the constructor or in the form's load event.

---

**Some Suggestions**

Give your methods meaningful names. For example, `carrSug()` is not very meaningful. Plus it does not follow the C# coding conventions--it looks like Java. Also, keep the method cohesive. You are doing some parts of the suggestion in the `carrSug()` and then some of it you are doing in `textBoxCliente_TextChanged`. Here is a more meaningful method:

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection clientSuggestions;
private void LoadClientSuggestions()
{
    this.clientSuggestions = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    string[] suggestionsFromFile = File.ReadLines("YourPath.txt").Select(x => x.Split('|').Skip(1).First()).ToArray();
    this.clientSuggestions.AddRange(suggestionsFromFile);
}
```

The above method uses Ling so make sure to import: `using System.Linq;`

Here is how to use it (Put this code in your form's constructor or Load method):

```
this.LoadSuggestions();
this.textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
this.textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteCustomSource = this.clientSuggestions;
this.textBoxCliente.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```

Why did I put the word `Load` in the method name? Because, it returns nothing so `Load` adds meaning.

Also, stop writing the same string multiple times:

```
"/Bd/clientes.txt"
```

Make that a constant so if you need to change it, you change it in one place.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I´ll be more carefull :)

Comment: So my program is doing what I whant but I have a problem and I don´t know how to fix it. When I write on the textBox I keep getting this error: **"System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempt to read or write to protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'"** . You know why it is happening?

Comment: I have no idea. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot) helps. You can also ask a new question with the new problem if you want and hopefully someone could help you.