# Fatal Execution Engine Error

Tags: c#, .net

All,

I have a console application which is written in .NET 3.5 which retrieves data from a database, does some calculations and post messages in a message queue. 
I run the .exe on my PC which runs without any problems. Deploying the .exe in a 64 bit server the application suddenly stops without any errors and when I use the DebugView utility I can see the below error.

```
[6276] Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A09C12F) (80131506)
```

I tried compiling with x64, x86 and Any CPU but still the same problem. I tried deploying to another server and still same situation. Anyone has an idea how I should proceed to determine the root cause?

Many Thanks,

MK

Comment: Put a try/catch inside your Main method and in the catch statement log the exception to get more details.

Comment: What's the OS for the server? What's the OS on your PC?

Comment: Server: Windows Server 2003 SP2
PC: Windows XP Sp3

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I have done this but there is no exception raised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting .NET "Fatal Execution Engine Error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823440/troubleshooting-net-fatal-execution-engine-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture a crash dump and analyze it for the root cause.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lexli/when-the-applicationprogram-crashes-on-windows)

If you like, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com