# Fatal Execution Error on Browser.ReadyState

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, clr, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting .NET “Fatal Execution Engine Error”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823440/troubleshooting-net-fatal-execution-engine-error)

My code is throwing a Fatal Execution Error. The exact error is this:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0xed40646c, on thread 0x2044. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

I'm not using unsafe user code as far as I know.

The code which is causing the issue is this one:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string pageHtml = client.DownloadString(url);

browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

browser.DocumentText = pageHtml;

do
 {
  Application.DoEvents();

  } while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete); //CRASH OCCURS HERE
```

Now here's the kicker. This code is beign run on a loop. Every so often, it gives this error. Sometimes its on the 1000th run. Last time it was on the 5545th run. It seems to be very random indeed.

How do I solve this problem? Or how can I get more information to solve it?

Comment: It may not be related, but the tight loop checking the RedayState rings immediate alarm bells.  Can you not listen for the DocumentCompleted event on the WebBrowser instead?

Comment: I used to do that (listen for the event) however that made it work asychronously, and I need to go through many webpages to the point where waiting seconds for it isn't an option. So no I can't really do that. This code is well behaved until you heavily use it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on [How to wait until WebBrowser is completely loaded in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275515/how-to-wait-until-webbrowser-is-completely-loaded-in-vb-net/9205751#9205751)

What u have to do is to add `bool _pageReady`  variable to `Completed` event.

```
void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var urlCurrent = e.Url.ToString();
            var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;

            if (!(urlCurrent.StartsWith("http://") || urlCurrent.StartsWith("https://")))
            {
                // in AJAX     
            }
            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != browser.Url.AbsolutePath)
            {
                // IFRAME           
            }
            else
            {
                //  DOCUMENT IS LOADED 100%
                Debug.WriteLine("DocumentCompleted " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());

                _pageReady = true; // Here it goes!!!! :)

                try
                {
                    mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 docs2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)web.Document.DomDocument;
                    mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 docs3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)web.Document.DomDocument;
                    mshtml.IHTMLElement2 body2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs2.body;
                    mshtml.IHTMLElement2 root2 = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)docs3.documentElement;

                    // Determine dimensions for the image; we could add minWidth here
                    // to ensure that we get closer to the minimal width (the width
                    // computed might be a few pixels less than what we want).
                    int width = Math.Max(body2.scrollWidth, root2.scrollWidth);
                    int height = Math.Max(root2.scrollHeight, body2.scrollHeight);

                    //get the size of the document's body
                    Rectangle docRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

                    web.Width = docRectangle.Width;
                    web.Height = docRectangle.Height;

                    //if the imgsize is null, the size of the image will 
                    //be the same as the size of webbrowser object
                    //otherwise  set the image size to imgsize
                    Rectangle imgRectangle;
                    if (imgsize == null) imgRectangle = docRectangle;
                    else imgRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle() { Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), Size = imgsize.Value };

                    //create a bitmap object 
                    __Bitmap = new Bitmap(imgRectangle.Width, imgRectangle.Height);

                    //Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                    //__Bitmap.SetResolution(resolution.Width, resolution.Height); 

                    //get the viewobject of the WebBrowser
                    IViewObject ivo = web.Document.DomDocument as IViewObject;

                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(__Bitmap))
                    {
                        //get the handle to the device context and draw
                        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                        ivo.Draw(1, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
                                 IntPtr.Zero, hdc, ref imgRectangle,
                                 ref docRectangle, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                    }

                    //var randomPart = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
                    //__Bitmap.Save(@"D:\t" + randomPart + ".png");

                    if (CropRectangle != null)
                    {
                        if (CropRectangle.Width > 0 && CropRectangle.Height > 0)
                        {
                            Bitmap bmpCrop = __Bitmap.Clone(CropRectangle, __Bitmap.PixelFormat);
                            __Bitmap = bmpCrop;
                        }
                    }

                    //__Bitmap.Save(@"D:\cropped" + randomPart + ".png");

                    bitmapPointer = __Bitmap.GetHbitmap();
                }
                catch
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
                }
            }
        }
```

and also  to do something like

```
public void HtmlCapture2()
        {
            try
            {
                if (web == null)
                    web = InitWebBrowser();

                web.Navigate(_navigateURL);

                try
                {
                    while (_pageReady == false) // YEAH!!!!!! IT IS WORKING!!!!
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                     }
                    //Thread.Sleep(WaitForWebsite); --- It works but....
                    //while (web.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) --- it gives an ERROR
                    //    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```